# Cocoa Close/Hide/Change Tab Notification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tabbed

is there any way to detect when a cocoa window has been closed, hidden and/or the user has changed the tab on which he was before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use notifications to broadcast such information throughout your application:

[NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

you can find some good information & examples in the iTunes U podcasts of brad larson.

this one here is a pretty great tutorial as well: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html

an absolut basic tutorial example can be found here: http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/dead-simple-nsnotification-example-iphone/

Comment: So using a notification, I can specify the 'event' (i.e. window hidden / window closed / etc) ? 

I will have a look at the documentation on NSNotification and check out the iTunes U Podcast

Comment: you can create a notificationcenter, let your classes 'listen' to notifications of that center. 
within your code you will be able to broadcast a notification to the center and the 'listeners' wil be able to react on it =)

Comment: i added another link to my answer - a great tutorial & example on notifications =)

Comment: Thank you! Marked as the answer (when the site allows me to do so :)!

Comment: Thanks for all the resources Sebastien. However, I still cannot understand how I can call the observer when one of the actions above happen.

How can I know that a window has been closed/hidden or tabbed?

Comment: Regarding the closing of the window I've found the notification NSWindowWillCloseNotification which seems to be doing the trick.. 

Any other help regarding the other 2 actions? Thanks!

Comment: NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification does the trick for minimizing the window... 

However for moving from tab to tab, I'm still finding some problems...