# Cocoa - finding out when a window has been closed, minimized or tabbed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotification

how do you find out when a cocoa application has been closed, minimized or tabbed?

I have read up on NSNotifications however, I still cannot understand how I can find out when the user has done any of the 3 actions above.

Thank you for any input

Comment: possible double-post of [Cocoa Close/Hide/Change Tab Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826719/cocoa-close-hide-change-tab-notification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your controller class conform to the [NSWindowDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and implement [windowWillMiniaturize:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillMiniaturize%3a) and [windowWillClose:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillClose%3a) and they will be called just before the window does the action.

Do the same with the [NSTabView delegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTabViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and implement [tabView:willSelectTabViewItem:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTabViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTabViewDelegate/tabView%3awillSelectTabViewItem%3a).

Some cocoa classes also send out notifications that are the same or similar to their delegate protocol, for example: [NSWindow Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIEBJDE). You can use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to [listen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-CEGCCFID) to these events. You have to look at the documentation to find out what exists.